# Smart Diagram Horizontal flow chart

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

I want to connect my DT block to LL in the following plot
[image]

The following code is:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}


\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!10, blue!30,blue!50},back arrow disabled=true,
additions={
additional item offset=0.4cm,
additional arrow color=blue!30,
additional arrow tip=stealth,
additional arrow line width=1pt,
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shape=rounded corners,
additional item bottom color=blue!30,
additional item shadow=drop shadow
}
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{WRA, LL, CM}{
above of module2/DT
}
%\smartdiagramconnect{->}{module2/additional-module2n}
\end{figure}
\end{center
```

}

However when I try to connect the new block to module 2 I get an error. Stating that "additional-module2" is not known.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Your problem you can solve onto two ways:

- With adding to `additions` the code line `additional connections disabled=false,` :
- Or to diagram code add `\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module2/additional-module1}`

First example:

```
\documentclass[rgb]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!10, blue!30,blue!50},back arrow disabled=true,
additions={
additional item offset=0.4cm,
additional connections disabled=false,  % NEW
additional arrow color=red,             % changed color ...
additional arrow tip=stealth,
additional arrow line width=2pt,        % changed thickness
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shape=rounded corners,
additional item bottom color=blue!30,
additional item shadow=drop shadow
}
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]%
    {WRA, LL, CM}%
    {above of module2/EDT}
%
\caption{Smart diagram}
\label{fig:smartdiagram}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Second case:

```
\documentclass[rgb]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!10, blue!30,blue!50},back arrow disabled=true,
additions={
additional item offset=0.4cm,
additional arrow color=red,             % changed color ...
additional arrow tip=stealth,
additional arrow line width=2pt,        % changed thickness
additional item border color=gray,
additional item shape=rounded corners,
additional item bottom color=blue!30,
additional item shadow=drop shadow
}
}
\smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]%
    {WRA, LL, CM}%
    {above of module2/EDT}
\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module2/additional-module1}
%
\caption{Smart diagram}
\label{fig:smartdiagram}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the both case the result is the same:

[image]

Comment: What about this command then "\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{sequence-item2/additional-module1}"?

Comment: @JPV, this command is not suported at`flow diagram`. Corect syntax in this case is `\smartdiagramconnect{to-}{module2/additional-module1}`. See edited answer.